# sending POST requests not returning data

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, request

I have this code below, using the `npm.js` api `request`

```
let inputContent = {
  prompt: req.body.prompt
}

inputContent.prompt = JSON.stringify(inputContent.prompt)
request.post({
  url: 'https://my.api.com/',
  headers : {
    "content-type": "application/json",
  },
  body: { 
    "prompt": inputContent.prompt,
    "max_tokens": 4000
  },
  json: true
}, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
      console.log(err)
  } else {
      console.log("body response is")
      console.log(body)
  }
})
```

I expect a response through `body`, but it keeps returning `undefined`. I also tried using `form` instead of `body`, and i tried removing `json`. Could anyone offer some advice?

Comment: Is the API *supposed* to return anything? There's not much here anyone can use to help; we don't even know what `request` is (the old `request` module that's been deprecated for two years?)

Comment: @DaveNewton i guess i was looking for someone to validate that this is actually the proper way to send a request, and im not going in loops here. and yes, it is the `request` module that has been deprecated for a few years. I've used it recently in another app for a much simpler use case, but I guess i should maybe consider switching, lol?

Comment: I suggest you switch to Fetch.